# Store special character in database table sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to store values which contains special character like ', " etc in database table filed which have datatype varchar. Like I want to store 'Sale'sStore' value in table.

How can I store it. Currently I was not able to store it.

Comment: You should be able to store it. How are you trying to insert it? You might just need to escape the quotes

Comment: means I have to use \ character. Currently I am inserting a record in sql server which contains apostrophy and I am inserting it like insert int tbl values(1 , 'abc's')

Comment: using sql-server queries you need to double your single quotes like this:   insert into tbl values(1 , 'abc''s')

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works for me. I am able to insert values.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where from are you trying to insert these strings. If manualy, so just insert \ before ' and it should be fine. If you are creating your query programatically, you should consider using binding function to build the query(they will solve it automatically) and not build them just with concatenating strings